# HTML disable enter in my code

Tags: php, html

I have this code

```
<a href="
        ?page=<?php echo $_GET['page'] ?>
        &tab=<?php echo $_GET['tab'] ?>
        &subtab=list"                                
Nazwa</a>
```

Chrome renders the above code as this:

```
                            ?page=nurk-edycja-tresci-home                                &tab=artykuly                                &subtab=list
```

With a lot of whitespaces :C I know a cause comming from my coding style but for me this improves readability a lot. Is there any solution to reconcile my style with browsers? ;)

Comment: Well, there's some XSS vulnerable code.

Comment: Can't you put the double quotes just before the question mark?

Comment: Quote each line of your multi-line strings...server side and concatenate them.

Answer (score 3):

## Keeping the white-space server-side

**It also doesn't look like your HTML syntax is valid, you're missing a `>`**
When the PHP is preprocessed, it won't return any of the whitecaps in the code so you should be good:

```
<a href="<?php
        echo '?page' . $_GET['page'];
        echo '&tab'  . $_GET['tab'];
        echo '&subtab=list";
?>">Nazwa</a>
```

You could also put the whitespace in `<?php ?>` so the server will process it and then return it to the client

```
<a href="<?php
    ?>?page=<?=$_GET['page'] ?><?php
    ?>&tab=<?=$_GET['tab'] ?><?php
    ?>&subtab=list"
>Nazwa</a>
```

You can also replace `<?php echo` with `<?=`

## How I would do it

```
<a href="<?= '?page=', $_GET['page'], '&tab', $_GET['tab'], '&subtab=list' ?>">
```

This syntax is very readable and also let's you put newlines:

```
<a href="<?=
  '?page=', $_GET['page'],
  '&tab', $_GET['tab'],
  '&subtab=list' 
?>">
```

## JavaScript?

If you *really* like your code right now, you can use JavaScript to get rid of the spaces:

```
(function () {
    window.onload = function () {
        var elems = document.getElementsByTagName('a'),
            i     = 0;
        for (; i < elems.length; i += 1) {
            elems[i].href = (elems[i].href || '').replace(/\s/g, '');
        }
    }
}());
```

Even shorter:

```
window.onload = function () {  Array.prototype.forEach.call(document.getElementsByTagName('a'), function (t) {  t.href = (t.href || '').replace(/\s/g, '')  })  }
```

ECMAScript2015 (Harmony):

```
window.onload = () => Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('a[href]')).map(t => (t.href = a.href.replace(/\s/g, ''));
```

Comment: Or keep the code as in the question, but put the white space between `<?php` and `?>`.

Comment: @GolezTrol Was just about to add that

Answer (score 1):

You *can* solve it by moving the PHP close tag, (and the opening quote), although it still doesn't look very nice:

```
<a href=
        "?page=<?php echo $_GET['page'] 
        ?>&tab=<?php echo $_GET['tab'] 
        ?>&subtab=list">                                
Nazwa</a>
```

But personally, I would choose to build the url earlier, so you just have to output a small variable in your HTML:

```
<?php

// I know you can use array items in strings too, but I like to split it up.
$page = $_GET['page'];
$tab = $_GET['tab'];
$url = "?page=$page&tab=$tab&subtab=list";

?>

<a href="<?=$url?>">
  Nazwa
</a>
```

[opinion] I think the last way is better. You have just a simple variable to output, which is constructed somewhere else. This way it's also much easier to move the HTML to a separate template. Such template should contain as little logic as possible and concatting variables should not be there. [/opinion]